# How to insert two lines for every data frame using awk?

Tags: awk, insert, lines

I have repeating data as follows

```
....
 4 4 4 66 79 169 150 0  40928  40938  40923  40921  40789  40000  40498
 5 4 3 16 22 247 0  40168  40911  40944  40205  40000  40562
 6 4 4 17 154 93 309 0  40930  40919  40903  40917  40852  40000  40419
 7 3 2 233 311 0  40936  40932  40874  40000  40807
....
```

This data is made up of 115 data blocks, and each data block have 4000 lines like that format. 
 Here, I hope to put two new lines (number of line per data block = 4000 and empty line) at the begining of each data blocks, so it looks

```
4000

 1 4 4 244 263 704 952 0  40936  40930  40934  40921  40820  40000  40570
 2 4 4 215 172 305 33 0  40945  40942  40937  40580  40687  40000  40410
 3 4 4 344 279 377 1945 0  40933  40915  40907  40921  40839  40000  40437
 4 4 4 66 79 169 150 0  40928  40938  40923  40921  40789  40000  40498
...
 3999 2 2 4079 4081 0  40873  40873  40746  40000  40634
 4000 1 1 4080 0  40873  40923  40000  40345
4000

 1 4 4 244 263 704 952 0  40936  40930  40934  40921  40820  40000  40570
 2 4 4 215 172 305 33 0  40945  40942  40937  40580  40687  40000  40410
 3 4 4 344 279 377 1945 0  40933  40915  40907  40921  40839  40000  40437
 4 4 4 66 79 169 150 0  40928  40938  40923  40921  40789  40000  40498
...
```

Can I do this with awk or any other unix command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one liner using `awk` can do the purpose.

`awk 'NR%4000==1{print "4000\n"} {print$0}' file`

what it does.

`print $0` prints every line.

`NR%4000==1` selects the `4000`th line. When it occures it prints a `4000` and a newline `\n`, that is two new lines.

`NR` Number of records, which is effectivly number of lines reads so far.

simple test.

inserts 4000 at 5th line

`awk 'NR%5==1{print "4000\n"} {print$0}'`

output:

```
4000

1
2
3
4
5
4000

6
7
8
9
10
4000

11
12
13
14
15
4000

16
17
18
19
20
4000
```

Comment: Could you please compare the first three lines of your output with the first three lines of the requirement example? Your one liner should have been written as `NR%4000==1{print "4000\n} 1`, so that an header is printed before printing the lines #1, #4001, #8001 etc.

Comment: It is `NR%4000==1{print "4000\n"} 1` (with both an opening and a **closing** double quote...).

Comment: @gboffi you got me. Corrected. Thank you :)

Comment: I see two small defects yet... (1) the `file` argument in your first line of code needs a space to be separated from the awk program and (2) you forgot to update the description of your algorithm, description that still refers to your previous implementation.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is more general, since the blocks can be of non-equal lenght as long as you restart the 1st field counter to denote the beginning of a new block

```
% cat mark_blocks
$1<count { print count; print "";
           for(i=1;i<=count;i++) print l[i]; }
# executed for each line
         { l[$1] = $0; count=$1}
END      { print count; print "";
           for(i=1;i<=count;i++) print l[i]; }
% awk -f mark_blocks your_data > marked_data
%
```

The working is simple, awk accumulates lines in memory and it prints the header lines and the accumulated data when it reaches a new block or EOF.

The (modest) trick is that the output action must take place before we do the usual stuff we do for each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in bash :

```
cat $FILE | ( let countmax=4000; let count=countmax; while read lin ; do if [ $count == $countmax ]; then let count=0; echo -e "$countmax\n" ; fi ; echo $lin ; let count=count+1 ; done )
```

Here we assume you are reading this data from $FILE . Then all we are doing is reading from the file and piping it into our little bash script.

The bash script reads lines one by one (with the `while read lin`) , and increments the counter `count`for each line. When starting or when the counter `count` reaches the value `countmax` (set to 4000) , then it prints out the 2 lines you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, but this give me two more empty lines, not 1 empty line. So, this code results 3 additional lines.