# Combine END and another condition like in `$1<count || END`

Tags: awk

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320609) I wrote the following `awk` code

```
% cat mark_blocks
$1<count { print count; print "";
           for(i=1;i<=count;i++) print l[i]; }
# executed for each line
         { l[$1] = $0; count=$1}
END      { print count; print "";
           for(i=1;i<=count;i++) print l[i]; }
%
```

where the actions that I wrote for `$0<count` and for the `END` condition are exactly the same.

I fancied that I could write a single condition, as

```
$1<count||END{print count;print "";for(i=1;i<=count;i++)print l[i];}
```

but what I got was

```
awk: e.awk:1: $1<count||END{print count;print "";for(i=1;i<=old;i++)print l[i]; }
awk: e.awk:1:           ^ syntax error
```

I've searched an answer for a while, but maybe because English is not my mother tongue, or maybe because it is impossible ;-) I was unable to find one.

Any idea? tia

Comment: ps: the statement "It is not possible", if backed up by clear evidence, is of course a possibly perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `END` block in the `awk` script is excecuted only when the script has finished processing all its records.

So it can be considerd as a finalizing  statement where there is no present record read to obtain $1 as you expect.

In short the `END` block is excecuted only once, evidently at the end.

Where as you can perfecty use `||` or as you have, in the normal block

eg

`awk '$1==1||$1==2{ print$0}'`

will print all records where `$1` is `1` or `2`.

for on input

```
1
2
3
4
```

output will be

```
1
2
```